# how can I use Jquery check li checkbox value?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, html-lists

I have a ul with 2 li items, after a user check the check box, by saveBtn button, how can I use jquery to check which li is checked?

```
<ul id="DATE_29_CB_P" class= "new-select" >
<li class="d"><input type="checkbox" onclick="onlyOne(this)" name="check" >07:30-09:00 </li>
<li class="d"><input type="checkbox" onclick="onlyOne(this)" name="check" >07:30-09:00 </li>
</ul>



<button id="DATE_29_CB_P_SUBBMIT" class="save it" onclick="saveBtn(this)">Save it!</button>

//In the saveBtn function, I have the following codes.
$("#DATE_29_CB_P li").each(function() {
    
            if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop(
                  ":checked")) {
                    console.log("Check box in Checked");
                } else {
                    console.log("Check box is not Checked");
                }
    });
```

it never hit the true case, I am new to jquery, spent few hours testing and can not get it to work. I need to know which one is checked, also get the html text. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `checked` not `:checked`.

Example:

```js
$('#DATE_29_CB_P_SUBBMIT').on('click', function() {
  $("#DATE_29_CB_P li").each(function(index, item) {
    if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked")) {
      console.log("Check box in Checked");
      console.log(index); //Index start with 0 so when it's zero, 1st check box is checked.
      console.log($(this).text());
    } else {
      console.log("Check box is not Checked");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="DATE_29_CB_P" class="new-select">
  <li class="d"><input type="checkbox" name="check">07:30-09:00 </li>
  <li class="d"><input type="checkbox" name="check">07:30-09:10 </li>
</ul>



<button id="DATE_29_CB_P_SUBBMIT" class="save it">Save it!</button>
```

Or use `.is(":checked"))`:

```js
$('#DATE_29_CB_P_SUBBMIT').on('click', function() {
  $("#DATE_29_CB_P li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
      console.log("Check box in Checked");
    } else {
      console.log("Check box is not Checked");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="DATE_29_CB_P" class="new-select">
  <li class="d"><input type="checkbox" name="check">07:30-09:00 </li>
  <li class="d"><input type="checkbox" name="check">07:30-09:00 </li>
</ul>
<button id="DATE_29_CB_P_SUBBMIT" class="save it">Save it!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Another questions, I updated the code a bit. $("#DATE_29_CB_P li input[type=checkbox]") .each(function() { if ($(this).prop("checked")) {//true}else{//false}}); Then If I want to also get the checked box's text info, I tried console.log($("#DATE_29_CB_P_SUBBMIT li").text()) in the true case, it will print all the li option text, is there a way to just print the selected one only? It looks like I will have to add a id to each li? Or is there a way to get it like an array by index?

Comment: **which one is checked** ? Check index for that.  I change my answer. See 1st example.

Comment: Index start with 0 so when it's zero, 1st check box is checked.

Comment: But if first li has text info as "07:30-09:00", second has "09:30-10:00", if the second one is checked, how to get the "09:30-10:00" text data?

Comment: I did another call, like ("#DATE_29_CB_P li").each(function() { data.push($(this).text());} Then when check the checkbox status, use the index to print array data; I wonder if there is a way to process them together instead of two different loops.

Comment: See updated example 1st to get checked value.

Comment: Thanks!! So for(each li)->check(li->input:checkbox), if true, print li's text! My 2 loop way is so ugly. Lol Thank you sir again!